# How to use Generics to handle dictionaries and arrrays

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am new to using generics but as according to my requirement I need to use it.

I have like 10 apis in which

- 4 returns array of custom objects(like multiple Person object data([Person]))
- 4 returns simple a object(like Company object data(Company))
- two return simple dictionary

so what I'm trying to do is to create a common Response class

```
class Response<T>: NSObject {
    @objc var responseData = T
}
```

But it is giving error on this line.

How should I suppose to use it so that it fulfills the requirements.

Comment: While there are several syntactic errors here (and Alastar helps fix those), this whole approach is very unlikely to do anything. There's no useful difference here between returning `Response<Company>` and `Company`. (What method do you plan to call on Response that you couldn't just call on T?) What do you expect the calling code to look like?  That will drive your generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all generics cannot be represented in objc. so you need to use only Swift

```
class Response<T> {
    var responseData: T!
}
```

you can use then `T` like this:

```
let response = Response<[String]>()
```

so `response.responseData` will be an array of `String`